# Exchange Web Services Streaming Subscription timeout when opening connection

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am currently troubleshooting an issue related to Exchange Web Services. The issue is that, upon opening a connection to a Streaming Subscription (via the StreamingSubscriptionConnection object), the operation hangs when calling the Open method. Here is the code that hangs, for reference:

```
_streamingSubscriptionConnection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(_exchangeService, _connectionLifetime);
_streamingSubscriptionConnection.AddSubscription(_subscription);
_streamingSubscriptionConnection.OnNotificationEvent += new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.NotificationEventDelegate(OnNotificationEvent);
_streamingSubscriptionConnection.OnSubscriptionError += new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.SubscriptionErrorDelegate(OnSubscriptionError);
_streamingSubscriptionConnection.OnDisconnect += new StreamingSubscriptionConnection.SubscriptionErrorDelegate(OnDisconnect);
_streamingSubscriptionConnection.Open();
```

It usually takes about two minutes and then it throws a `ServiceRequestException` whose message is:

> The request has failed. The operation has timed out.

It's also worth mentioning that even if I set the timeout to a minute, it will still take longer than a minute and then throw this exception. The call never gets past that Open command.

My questions are, has anyone come across this in the past? Additionally, are there any tools available that I can use to diagnose any connection issues to determine if the exception is on my end, the Exchange servers end, or somewhere in the middle? I've tried Fiddler and Microsoft Network Monitor to look for any patterns but I'm having a hard time discerning anything.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To add on to this, if I add a trace listener I get quite a lot of output. I can see it retrieve the Subscription Id and then attempt to connect. When it sends out the request to connect, this is what is logged between the time the Open command is issued and the timeout:

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="10" Time="2013-01-24 19:16:18Z">
      POST /ews/exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
      Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
      Accept: text/xml
      User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/14.03.0032.000
      Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate      
</Trace>

<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="10" Time="2013-01-24 19:16:18Z" Version="14.03.0032.000">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Header>
            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1" />
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <m:GetStreamingEvents>
                <m:SubscriptionIds>
                    <t:SubscriptionId>GABsdGNmaXN3bXNnY2EwNi5mbmZpcy5jb20QAAAAnQCowdNSt0iTEhqVr8+a1GPHu2t+yM8I</t:SubscriptionId>
                </m:SubscriptionIds>
                <m:ConnectionTimeout>30</m:ConnectionTimeout>
            </m:GetStreamingEvents>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

I'm attempting to rule out network issues, but having a bit of a hard time doing so. Any advice is welcome at this point.

Comment: You specifically do NOT want to use Fiddler for this purpose, because Exchange's RPC-over-HTTPS abuses the HTTP protocol such that it WILL hang if you use it through a buffering proxy like Fiddler. You could try NetMon/Wireshark to see whether there's ANY traffic...

Comment: I tried Wireshark first, but it turns out my place of employment blocks Wireshark but not Fiddler. I'll have to try to get it unblocked at this point. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Actually it turns out Fiddler was able to help with this. It turns out that our Exchange web service is just extremely slow at accepting connections (like, > 2 minutes every time). Just seeing that it was returning a response after the timeout elapsed was help enough. I hadn't noticed that on my initial inspection. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who come after me, this issue wound up not being anything related to .Net or the EWS library.

The issue wound up being related to persistence settings on the load balancers in our company. With our load balancers, if any kind of persistence is enabled for EWS streaming subscription calls, those connections will fail. Unfortunately, at the time I wasn't aware there was a load balancer between myself and the Exchange server since developers don't have access to that infrastructure here.

Regardless, hopefully this helps someone out in the future!

Comment: Might be causing my slow connection to the outlook365.com servers. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Perhaps this helps anyone: For debugging this issue the EwsEditor (https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor) was a great tool (as so often). It showed the same errors for streaming notifications as our application did, and when bypassing the load balancer, everything worked as it should again.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me when I add many subscriptions to the connection, that the connection will take long time to open. Try to increase the amount of `_connectionLifetime`  to 20 mins and see what will happen.

Comment: It actually times out way before that connection lifetime expires, within the same ~2 minute time frame mentioned before.

Comment: Oh, in this case probably it is something with the network protocols, maybe the firewall is on ? this is not my specialty anymore :)